# Openssh - Allow root to access both sftp and ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp

I want to configure sftp on my server to be accessed by root user.

I changed my configuration of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
Compression no
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 4
#Other options are commented
[...]
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server

Match user root
ChrootDirectory /
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

It works and I can connect by sftp to my server, but now I can connect by ssh anymore. I got this message:

`This service allows sftp connections only.`

The same happen with `Match group root`

How can I configure sftp to allow root but keeping ssh too?

---

### Update:

Commenting ForceCommand internal-sftp option ssh still works but I cannot connect by sftp.
sshd_config:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
Match user root
ChrootDirectory /
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
#ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Error:

```
user@notebook:~$ sftp root@my_device
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'my_device' differs from the key for the IP address 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
Offending key for IP in /home/myUser/.ssh/known_hosts:78
Matching host key in /home/myUer/.ssh/known_hosts:93
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

On the server side:

```
root@my_device:~# cat /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh
2024-01-17T19:25:21.659884+00:00 my_device sshd[30592]: Accepted none for root from xx.xx.xx.xx port 38024 ssh2
2024-01-17T19:25:21.881328+00:00 my_device sshd[30592]: Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx port 38024:11: disconnected by user
2024-01-17T19:25:21.881997+00:00 my_device sshd[30592]: Disconnected from user root xx.xx.xx.xx port 38024
```

Note: If I also remove `Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server` as I got a different error when trying to connect by sftp:
`subsystem request failed on channel 0`

Comment: Can you please provide your running sshd config with `sshd -T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem here was that `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` doesn't exist in the server side. I added it in the image with a new Yocto build and then I was able to connect by ssh and sftp with root using the default config:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Answer (score 6):

The `ForceCommand` directive only allows root to use sftp, try commenting out that line.

Comment: Already done but didn't work. In that case, root can connect by ssh but not by sftp. I need both

Comment: @Baffer Also remove the susbsytem line, let it use the internal sftp server. You likely made an error in the path to that executeable

Comment: @Baffer What error do you get? I replicated your settings without the `ForceCommand` line and it works fine for me. You might need to share the rest of your config file, and it also might be good to know what you're actually trying to achieve with these settings. If all you wanted is access with both ssh and sftp you didn't need the `Match user` block

Comment: I updated the post with some test with `ForceCommand`. If `ForceCommand` is present, only sftp is allow. If not, only ssh is allow.

On the other hand, `Match user` doesn't seems to change anything if it's set or not (so I'll remove it). But with or without `Match user`, the behavior is the same and depends on `ForceCommand`

Comment: The file `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` doesn't exit. I don't even know why sftp works with my config

Comment: @Baffer That's strange indeed, did you copy that setting from somewhere online? That location isn't universal, for example mine is at `/usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server`. You could try something like `find / | grep sftp-server` to find yours

Answer (score 5):

The OpenSSH man page [sshd_config(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) describes this:

> [`ForceCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand)
>
> Forces the execution of the command specified by `ForceCommand`, ignoring any command supplied by the client and `~/.ssh/rc` if present. The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the `-c` option. This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution. It is most useful inside a `Match` block. The command originally supplied by the client is available in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable. Specifying a command of `internal-sftp` will force the use of an in-process SFTP server that requires no support files when used with `ChrootDirectory`. The default is `none`.

As told here, your `ForceCommand internal-sftp` only allows SFTP.

Furthermore, [`PermitRootLogin yes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitRootLogin) is dangerous as it enables password authentication for root, and [`ChrootDirectory /`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory) is not really a limiting *chroot jail* at all. It is recommended to

- use public key authentication for `root` or disable `root` login altogether
- use `sudo` instead of direct `root` login
- use public key authentication for any users having `sudo` privileges
- use password for `sudo` (together with the previous it is effectively an MFA for the escalated privileges).

I keep reminding of these as Server Fault is for questions related to business environments and your current configuration does not demonstrate reasonable practices in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run this ansible playbook which checks your ssh configuration and creates a secure ssh configuration.
https://github.com/dev-sec/ansible-collection-hardening/tree/master/roles/ssh_hardening

After running this You then only need to allow rootlogin in the sshd_config and then both ssh and sftp should work